# Imput NaNs with the mean in column and find percentage of missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to impute the mean value at all the missing values of the column `Product_Base_Margin` and then print the percentage of missing values in each column.

My current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')


df = df[~np.isnan(df['Product_Base_Margin'])]
print(round(100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index)), 2))
```

Expected output:

```
Ord_id                 0.00
Prod_id                0.00
Ship_id                0.00
Cust_id                0.00
Sales                  0.24
Discount               0.65
Order_Quantity         0.65
Profit                 0.65
Shipping_Cost          0.65
Product_Base_Margin    0.00
dtype: float64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result of the current code? And what is the result that you want?

Answer (score 0):

I've used `matplotlib` just to better show results... You find number of NaNs by using `isnull()` / `isna()`

To insert mean where it's NaN.  `fillna()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=[10,5],
                      sharey=True, sharex=False)


df.loc[:,"Product_Base_Margin"].isnull().to_frame().value_counts().plot(ax=ax[0], kind="bar")
df.loc[:,"Product_Base_Margin"].fillna(df.loc[:,"Product_Base_Margin"].mean(), inplace=True)
df.loc[:,"Product_Base_Margin"].isnull().to_frame().value_counts().plot(ax=ax[1], kind="bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Expected output of the above question is Ord_id                 0.00
Prod_id                0.00
Ship_id                0.00
Cust_id                0.00
Sales                  0.24
Discount               0.65
Order_Quantity         0.65
Profit                 0.65
Shipping_Cost          0.65
Product_Base_Margin    0.00
dtype: float64

Comment: so just calc / plot it . not sure what your question is if you know the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
df['Product_Base_Margin'] = df['Product_Base_Margin'].mean()

print(round(100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index)), 2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).